# resetting the image in an NSView

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I think this is a very simple question, but I’m new to programming so I may be going about it in a wrong-headed way.

I have a basic understanding of Objective-C writing terminal applications and am teaching myself how to use the Cocoa GUI.

I understand how to use `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` to connect a simple button to a method that will repeatedly send random numbers to a textfield.

I understand how to add a `NSView` file, connect it to a custom view in interface builder and draw a path through random points in the view when the application launches.

(I’ve been putting this code inside the `- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect` method that is declared when the file is created).

What I can’t seem to figure out is how to connect a button to an action that will then ‘refresh’ the view – in this case repopulate it with another set of random points connected with a path.  Looking at the documentation, I think I should somehow be using

```
– (void) setNeedsDisplay(BOOL)flag
```

but nothing I have tried so far had worked.  Please tell me, what am I missing here?

Comment: WOW! what a sea of letters... imagine Apple Documentation written the way you write :-/ Can you please give spaces, indents, styles, etc to your writing in order to be better and simply read by all of us? Ty!

Comment: sorry! Hope this is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)refreshButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [theView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Connect your button to that action. "theView" is a reference to your custom NSView.

Comment: Thank you!  I had tried similar things, but I wasn't declaring my custom NSView as an instance variable in the AppController. Then I tried to add the button into the NSView and send 

[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

silly newbie :)